# joined table INSERT statement

Tags: php, html, join, phpmyadmin

I have 3 tables. tbl_info, tbl_trainings, and tbl_infotrainings where tbl_infotrainings is used to join tbl_info and tbl_trainings.

tbl_trainings accepts multiple checkbox value.
tbl_trainings contains:

```
+------+-----------+
|  id  |  training |
+------+-----------+
```

tbl_infotrainings contains:

```
+------+-----------+---------------+
|  id  |  info_id  |  training_id  |
+------+-----------+---------------+
```

My problem here is when inserting new information. This is the codes I used:

for inserting the id of tbl_info(works fine)

```
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO tbl_infotrainings (info_id) (SELECT id FROM tbl_info)";
```

for inserting id of tbl_training(has errors)

```
$sql4 = "INSERT INTO tbl_infotrainings (training_id) (SELECT id FROM tbl_trainings)";
```

The desired output in the database would be:

```
+------+-----------+------------+
|  id  |  info_id  |  training  |
+------+-----------+------------+
|  1   |    1      |     1      |
+------+-----------+------------+
|  2   |    1      |     2      |
+------+-----------+------------+
|  3   |    1      |     3      |
+------+-----------+------------+
```

Here is the full code:

```
if($_POST["Submit"]=="Submit"){
$sql1="INSERT INTO tbl_info VALUES ('NULL', '$fname', '$mname', '$lname', '$street', '$barangay', '$city', '$number', '$month', '$day', '$year', '$status' , '$spouse', '$dependent')";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO tbl_infotrainings (info_id) (SELECT id FROM tbl_info)";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);
$sql4 = "INSERT INTO tbl_infotrainings (training_id) (SELECT id FROM tbl_trainings)";
$result4=mysql_query($sql4);
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkbox);$i++){
$sql2="INSERT INTO tbl_trainings VALUES ('NULL', '".$checkbox[$i]."')";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);    
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're missing one valuable piece of information to get some help - what is the error or undesirable result you are currently experiencing?

Comment: I really can't tell the error because I'm just using if else. but the training_id doesn't accept anything, just 0 in database

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `'NULL'` as textual value for (i presume) `AUTO_INCREMENT` id -- simply use `NULL` keyword.

```
...
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_info VALUES (NULL, '$fname', '$mname', '$lname', '$street', '$barangay', '$city', '$number', '$month', '$day', '$year', '$status' , '$spouse', '$dependent')"; // NULL not 'NULL'
    ...
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_trainings VALUES (NULL, '".$checkbox[$i]."')"; // NULL not 'NULL'
...
```